# DC Thevenin voltage

Tags: voltage, dc, homework, thevenin

The question I am trying to answer is:

> Find the Thevenin voltage Vth to the left of the 10-ohm resistor.

[image: schematic for the question]

I have determined Rth for the electrical circuit in the pictures (Rth = 5 ohms) but I am having difficulty recreating the electrical circuit and I do not know the steps to find Vth.

This is the solution I arrived at:

[image: attempted solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

> *I am having difficulty recreating the electrical circuit and I do not
> know the steps to find Vth*

The method I use is called circuit reduction. Can you see what I have done here (I've made a small step that reduces the resistor count by one item): -

[image]

The next step I would take would be to combine the 48 volt source and 20 Ω resistor into a current source and parallel resistor. The step after that would convert the 12 volt source and 5 Ω resistor to a current source and parallel resistor.

Then, after the above manipulations, you have two parallel current sources in parallel with two parallel resistors. That directly gives you the Thevenin voltage with the 10 Ω load open-circuit.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I really appreciate it....can you take a look of what I add?

Comment: There is another question... why, after I converted the current to volts... why did the resistor not disappear?

Comment: @Mustafadrees yes, 19.2 volts is the correct answer. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. You should also edit your question to indicate that the steps you took were following advice from my answer.

Comment: I have no idea what your 2nd comment is about.

Comment: Actually, yes, I still don't know how I got to this point. I feel like it was luck...but I appreciate your work...thank you very much...I will research it and try to understand it.

Comment: It's called Thevenin's theorem. Don't forget to read the link about what to do when someone answers a question you make.

Comment: It's okay thank you...I already did it